# How to store and change values for 2D lists?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a function that would sum up the rows of an array and have it displayed in one column at the beginning/end. It was initially done with a 2D array(`int[][]`) and  it works fine. I would now like to change the input to 2D lists(`List<List<Integer>>`) instead of arrays. This is the function that uses `int[][]` that currently works:

```
public static void sumLeft(int[][] numbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
            numbers[i][0] += numbers[i][j];
            numbers[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So if I take in this array:

```
10  15  30  40  
15  5   8   2   
20  2   4   2   
1   4   5   0
```

This would be the result:

```
95  0   0   0   
30  0   0   0   
28  0   0   0   
10  0   0   0
```

Now I want to do the same thing, but with 2D lists, or `List<List<Integer>>`.

This is what I currently have:

```
public static void listLeft(List<List<Integer>> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        List<Integer> innerList = list.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
            sum += list.get(i).get(j);
            innerList.set(0, sum);
            innerList.set(j, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

If I take in the same set of numbers, it would output this:

```
95  0   0   0   
125 0   0   0   
153 0   0   0   
163 0   0   0
```

*Notice that rows 2-4 have the wrong values.

Comment: Hint: there's a relationship between the sums of the implementation for arrays and the one for lists. Watch closely ;) (or use a debugger).

Answer (score 2):

Move `sum` into the `for` loop that spans the lists. Also, you don't need to set the first list item to sum with every item in the list; you can set it once at the end.

```
public static void listLeft(List<List<Integer>> list) {

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        List<Integer> innerList = list.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {

            sum += list.get(i).get(j);
            innerList.set(j, 0);
        }
        innerList.set(0, sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked. But what's the reasoning setting it once at the end as compared to the initial way it was done in the question.

Comment: @Zubair: In the second code example with Lists, you don't need to set the first item to `sum` repeatedly because the variable `sum` accumulates the sum all the way through to the end of each list. In your original code with the 2D array, you didn't need a `sum`variable because the first item in each row was the accumulator, so there you really did need to update that first item repeatedly. You can also see the difference because the inner loop in the first version starts with `j=1`, whereas the second code starts the inner loop with `j=0`.

Comment: do you have any idea how to adjust the loop so that the sum would be saved on the first/last row? So I would get something like this:


`46 26 47 44` 

`0 0 0 0` 

`0 0 0 0` 

`0 0 0 0`

Comment: @Zubair: Use each item in the first row as the accumulator. This approach will only work if the matrix is square. Basically use the first item as the accumulator for the first row, the second item as the accumulator for the second row, etc.